# import Excel file

Tags: c#

How can I import Excel file to C# project ?

Comment: Do you want to add it to a project or read the values into a C# program ? (e.g. convert it to a DataTable)

Comment: We need more details. What exactly are you trying to do? What do you ultimately want to accomplish?

Comment: i want edit this data in my project

Answer (score 1):

You can use Office Object Model to work with Excel sheets. Add a reference to [Microsoft.Excel.Interop assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wss56bz7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). You can use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/syyd7czh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) reference for working with excel sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it is in the correct folder in the project directory, then (assuming you are using Visual Studio) click on the show all files in the solution explorer (it is one of the small buttons at the top of the tool) and then right click the ecel file that should now show up and click add to project.

Answer (score 0):

Note the path to the Excel file is set dynamically:

```
// using System.Data.OleDb
OleDbConnection ExcelConection = null;
OleDbCommand ExcelCommand = null;
OleDbDataReader ExcelReader = null;
OleDbConnectionStringBuilder OleStringBuilder = null;

try
{
    OleStringBuilder =
        new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\MyExcel.xls;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1';");
    OleStringBuilder.DataSource = MapPath(@"~\App_Datav\MyExcelWorksheet.xls");

    ExcelConection = new OleDbConnection();
    ExcelConection.ConnectionString = OleStringBuilder.ConnectionString;

    ExcelCommand = new OleDbCommand();
    ExcelCommand.Connection = ExcelConection;
    ExcelCommand.CommandText = "Select * From [Sheet1$]";

    ExcelConection.Open();
    ExcelReader = ExcelCommand.ExecuteReader();

    GridView1.DataSource = ExcelReader;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
catch (Exception Args)
{
    LabelErrorMsg.Text = "Could not open Excel file: " + Args.Message;
}
finally
{
    if (ExcelCommand != null)
        ExcelCommand.Dispose();
    if (ExcelReader != null)
        ExcelReader.Dispose();
    if (ExcelConection != null)
        ExcelConection.Dispose();
}
```